# Is it allowed to use "Olympic Games" like a countable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, collective-nouns

I heard 'Olympic Games' is a collective noun, so it is uncountable.

When I'd like to refer to the Olympic Games held in particular year(s), can I treat it like a countable (and/or singular) noun?

- *Three* previous Olympic Games were held in Asia. (I'm referring to 2018, 2020, and 2022 Games)
- Next Olympic *Game is* held in Paris 2024.

Comment: It has to be *Games*. One game is a very short time in tennis! The next Olympic Games will be held in Paris in 2024.

Comment: It's a collection of all the events being held during the 2-week period. Each event could be considered a single game.

Comment: It would be interesting to have some explanation of what's going on grammatically when you talk about the Olympic Games vs three Olympic Games, rather than just an answer which asserts it is grammatical or cites examples.

Comment: It's interesting that "previous Oaks", "previous 2000 Guineas" etc where the noun is already plural in form are rarely found in non-attributive non-singular uses on the internet. " ... two previous Masters" in the usage we're looking for is somewhat more common. There is an awkwardness in the use of the pluralised plural-form (though Gollum would no doubt use 'Olympic Gameses' for both one and seven events).

Comment: 'Los Angeles was named as the host of the 2028 Olympics in a concurrent announcement for Paris in 2024. The 2028 Olympics will make Los Angeles just the third city (following London and Paris, respectively) to host three Olympic Games.' [[The Sporting News](https://www.sportingnews.com/us/athletics/news/olympics-locations-2022-2024/ccotmaklpfm3zdybc0kx1hoh#:~:text=Los%20Angeles%20was%20named%20as,1932%20and%201984%20Summer%20Games.)] It's allowable, but some examples sound far better than others.

Comment: I'd vote to re-open if reasonable research were shown; this is a tricky area. I'd say that plural-form compound nouns (or at least strong collocations) seem to resist use as plurals (though there aren't many anyway), with some phrasings sounding far worse than others..

Answer (score 1):

*Olympic Games* is a noun phrase rather than a collective noun (but see below). It refers to a set (forget the specialised use of *set* in tennis) of games, a collection of games. The use of the capitals emphasises that this noun phrase is a proper name.

> [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/proper-nouns/)
> A proper noun is a specific (i.e., not generic) name for a particular person, place, or thing. Proper nouns are always capitalized in English, no matter where they fall in a sentence. Because they endow nouns with a specific name, they are also sometimes called proper names.

Each Olympic Games is therefore a specific collection of games characterised by its purpose, time and place. It is consequently acceptable and logical to refer - for example - to the three Olympic Games in Asia.

---

Regarding **collective nouns**, many sources lay emphasis on their being single words. However, even if it were argued that *Olympic Games* is a "collective noun phrase", this seems to support the notion that we can talk of several such collectives, as in "Three Asiatic Olympic Games".

> [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/collective_nouns.htm)
> What Are Collective Nouns?
> A collective noun is the word used to represent a group of people, animals, or things.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/collective-noun)
> Countable
> A collective noun is a noun such as 'family' or ' team' that refers to a group of people or things.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collective%20noun)
> collective noun:
> a noun such as "team" or "flock" that refers to a group of people or things

> [Oxford Learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/collective-noun)
> a singular noun, such as committee or team, that refers to a group of people, animals or things and, in British English, can be used with either a singular or a plural verb. In American English it must be used with a singular verb.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/collective-noun?q=Collective+noun)
> a noun that describes a group of things or people as a unit:
> "Family" and "flock" are examples of collective nouns.

Comment: Why isn't 'Olympic Games' a collective noun, if it refers to a set? 'Team', referring to a set of players, is.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I asked myself this too but Collins, Merriam Webster and Cambridge seem to lay emphasis on a collective noun as a single word. Hence my slightly qualifying use of "rather than". I think I will edit my answer later to discuss this point. Many thanks.

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/town-council) class/es 'town council' as a compound noun rather than a strong collocation. But I'd certainly use logical rather than formal agreement (the town council was established in 1886 / the town council were divided over whether to allow fracking). To be fair, I'm struggling with 'Olympic Games'. I'm happy with 'He won gold in both the 1960 and 1964 Olympic Games' but far less so with ''Those two Olympic Games were the highlights of her career'. I'd say the latter is equally grammatical but heading for outlandish.